# Why does Active Directory close LDAP connections with [RST, ACK] instead of [FIN, ACK]?

Tags: windows, tcp, directory, ldap

This is more of a curiosity than a problem, as I don't see any negative impacts, but I am wondering why does Active Directory close LDAP connections with [RST, ACK] instead of [FIN, ACK] after a [FIN, ACK] from a client?

Just any simple LDAP search to Active Directory (Windows Server 2012 R2) will make a TCP connection that is terminated client-side but ACK'd by the server with a [RST, ACK] instead of a [FIN, ACK].

A search similar to this will reproduce this:

```
ldapsearch  -s sub -a always -x -h myhost.ad.corp.com -y passfile -D "administrator@ad.corp.com"  -b "dc=ad,dc=corp,dc=com" "(fsmoroleowner=*)"
```

Before running this, use tcpdump similar to this:

```
sudo tcpdump -w output.pcap port ldap
```

If you examine the packet capture file, you will see that the AD server responds to the client TCP close's [FIN, ACK] with a [RST, ACK]. Either way the connection is closed, but based on what I know about TCP, it seems more correct for the server to send a [FIN, ACK].